# The primary node of the queue manager is always starting as Running as standby

Tags: ibm-mq

Getting the below error message when starting the secondary node and The primary node of the queue manager is always starting as Running as standby
I want to primary node of my queue manager  should show the status as Running
AMQ7274 WebSphere MQ queue manager already has the maximum number of standby instances.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no queue manager is running on the primary and secondary nodes then I suspect a problem is likely with the locking(lock conflict) in the file system. If any MQ process is running on the primary and secondary nodes, then kill the processes and then try starting the queue manager again. If the problem still persists, I suggest a file system repair on the server and then unmounting and mounting the file system on the client node. A workaround for the problem would be to delete the files(master, active and standby) and then restart the queue manager. If the problem is only with the lock files then the workaround would be helpful. If there is any other file system issue in the queue manager files, then only a file system repair can resolve the issue. I also suggest checking the status using the command given below before attempting any recovery.

dspmq -x -m  -o all